# urllib2 Posting ZIP file error

Tags: python, curl, urllib2

I want to send my application/zip data to the server without pycurl or other libs. I am newbie with cURL. Firstly i succesfully sent text/xml data with this code

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request("http://192.168.79.131/rest", headers = {"Content-type" : "text/xml" , "Accept" : "*/*"} , data = '<income><name>acme7</name></income>')
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

But now i want to upload my ZIP file to the server. I tried this code:

```
import urllib2
zipPath = "c:/somedir/ways.zip"
zipData  = open(zipPath, "rb")
req = urllib2.Request("http://192.168.79.131/rest", headers = {"Content-type" : "application/zip" , "Accept" : "*/*"} , data = zipData)
f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

I got these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#25>", line 1, in <module>
    f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 386, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 248, in get_type
    **raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: /rest/income**
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like [Requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? It handles a lot of the urllib2 stuff so you don't have to:

```
import requests

url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
files = {'file': open('c:/somedir/ways.zip', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print r
```

Prints:

```
>>> <Response [200]>
```

Comment: Is that because you can't where you're running this? Or you don't think installing the lib is worth it?

Comment: I prefered urllib2 because maybe users dont want to install other libs (exactly newcomers)

Comment: It's a common practice to include external libraries (especially in the open source community). You're actually doing your users a favor by implementing requests because of its stability. It's a single line to install it and get it working as well, and drastically reduces your effort. If you're overly concerned about it, include a version as a dependency in your code (with the appropriate license).